# Start django liveserver with fixtures

Tags: django, fixtures

Is there any way to start the django development liveserver with a clean db and loaded with test fixtures of my choosing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, have a look at [the documentation for the `testserver` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#testserver-fixture-fixture):

> **django-admin testserver**
>
> Runs a Django development server (as in runserver) using data from the given fixture(s).
>
> For example, this command:
>
> ```
>    django-admin testserver mydata.json
> ```
>
> ...would perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Create a test database, as described in The test database.
> 2. Populate the test database with fixture data from the given fixtures. (For more on fixtures, see the documentation for loaddata above.)
> 3. Runs the Django development server (as in runserver), pointed at this newly created test database instead of your production database.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

You can load your fixtures into the db using the following command:

```
python manage.py loaddata data.json
```